# Any recourse for when an objectively wrong answer is Accepted, and also protected from criticism?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Let's say an objectively wrong answer was highly upvoted, selected as Best Answer, *and then all the normal options for recourse (comments, flags) were purged by a mod with a political bias in line with the wrong answer*?

Anything that can be done?

Comment: A mod cannot stop you downvoting. Nor can a mod accept an answer unless they happened to also ask the question. A mod cannot highly upvote an answer either so perhaps given the number of other upvoters the answer isn't as bad as you think it is?

Comment: @RobertLongson The mention of "political bias" suggests that it's possible the question was rather subjective, possibly on a site that allows for more subjectivity in their questions that other sites allow.

Comment: @Servy I think it's most likely [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/why-isnt-everybody-rich) If so, I don't think the site allows any more subjectivity than we're used to.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well that's certainly a very opinion based question, and a very opinion based answer.  I couldn't comment on whether or not it's appropriate enough on the site, but it's still highly subjective.

Comment: Without knowing the site-specific subjectivity level allowed, the accepted answer can still be objectively ruled out. There is oodles of math proving that changing one's personal behavior cannot allow "everybody to be rich", which is an old Calvinist dogma, not to mention absurd.

Comment: This is a known problem with both answer acceptance and the HNQ list. Stack Exchange has made it very clear that they consider these problems to be a good thing for absolutely no reason. Moderation is generally extremely good but there are plenty of edge cases where a bias is demonstrable, however they are not sufficient for action, and not should they be, since they are usually just adhering to the majority opinion of the general community (it's not the moderator maintaining the standard that is at fault, the problem is the standard itself).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well a mod *can't* purge flags.  They could decline them, but of course an answer being wrong isn't grounds for any flags, so declining them is entirely appropriate.  A mod also can't remove your downvote, which *is* the appropriate course of action for when you think an answer isn't useful.

As for the comments, it's possible that the way in which you went about explaining how the post needed to be improved was not constructive, if so, consider trying to present the information more constructively, such that a mod no longer has grounds to remove it.  If you feel that there were no grounds for removing the comment, and that it was important information for readers of the post, then you could consider posting on that site's meta or using the "contact us" form to discuss the appropriateness of the deletion of the comments (but you should be well prepared to explain why those comments really needed to be there and didn't merit deletion for any reason; such requests tend to be viewed rather skeptically, for good reason).

If you know the correct answer to the question, then you could provide your own answer and, in that answer, explain why it is correct and other solutions are not.  Note that it's not appropriate to post an answer just to critique another answer; you need to *answer the question* first and foremost, but as additional information you can explain why other approaches are not acceptable answers.  There are a lot more protections for answers over comments; there is a much higher standard required for them to be deleted, and deleted answers can be seen by more users, so if there really is inappropriate behavior going on there are more checks and balances.

As for the acceptance itself, you have no recourse there at all.  The question author is free to accept whatever answer they want, no matter how wrong/bad anyone thinks it is.